# Where's the HttpUtility.ParseQueryString Method in WinRT?

Tags: http, parsing, windows-8, windows-runtime, query-string

Since [HttpUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.aspx) is not available in WinRT, I was wondering if there's a straightforward way to parse HTTP query strings?

**Is there actually some equivalent to [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.web.httputility.parsequerystring.aspx) in WinRT?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Instead of `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` you can use [`WwwFormUrlDecoder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh825884.aspx).

Here's an example I grabbed [here](http://www.dzhang.com/blog/2012/08/21/parsing-uri-query-strings-in-windows-8-metro-style-apps)

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.UnitTestFramework;
using Windows.Foundation;

[TestClass]
public class Tests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestWwwFormUrlDecoder()
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://example.com/?a=foo&b=bar&c=baz");
        WwwFormUrlDecoder decoder = new WwwFormUrlDecoder(uri.Query);

        // named parameters
        Assert.AreEqual("foo", decoder.GetFirstValueByName("a"));

        // named parameter that doesn't exist
        Assert.ThrowsException<ArgumentException>(() => {
            decoder.GetFirstValueByName("not_present");
        });

        // number of parameters
        Assert.AreEqual(3, decoder.Count);

        // ordered parameters
        Assert.AreEqual("b", decoder[1].Name);
        Assert.AreEqual("bar", decoder[1].Value);

        // ordered parameter that doesn't exist
        Assert.ThrowsException<ArgumentException>(() => {
            IWwwFormUrlDecoderEntry notPresent = decoder[3];
        });
    }
}
```