# There is a way to send custom data in push notification in Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1, apple-push-notifications, windows-10

I know that are Raw Notifications on WNS but the whole content of the notification is showed in the notification. I wanted to do like APNS and GCM does. A custom properties in the json payload that it's delivered to the app but its not showed to the user. There is a way to do that in WNS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send parameters in `launch` attribute, it can be similar to url. For example, for toast notifications:

```
<toast launch="?param1=sample&param2=sample2">
</toast>
```

and parse it in the application. Value from `launch` attribute can be retrieved in `OnLaunched` handler. [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/Hh868212%28v=win.10%29.aspx) is an article about handling activation from a toast notification (from MSDN).

Note: you can put into `launch` any other format you want. I suggested *uri-based* parameter because it is easy to parse using `WwwFormUrlDecoder`, which is mentioned [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759686/wheres-the-httputility-parsequerystring-method-in-winrt).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will receive this launch attribute on OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args) as it says in https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/Hh868212%28v=win.10%29.aspx. But this method will be fired every time i received a toast notification with this attributte or just in the launch of the application? And you if this works in all platforms like Windows Phone 8/8.1 and Windows 10?

Comment: I've tested it on WinRT (Universal apps). Notification was shown always, even when app was launched (active). OnLaunched method was fired always when user pressed notification.